# Image captioning issue

Tags: html, css

```css
h2 span.spacer {
   padding:0 5px;
}
h2 span { 
   color: white; 
   font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   padding: 10px; 
}
h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 50px; 
   left: 0; 
}
```

```html
<h2><span>This is the first line.<span class="spacer"></span><br/><span class="spacer"></span>This is the second line.</span></h2>
```

Grettings!

So I've developed a funky way of captioning an image as illustrated in the code below. However, as you can see, there are black blocks at the end of the first line and the beginning of the second line which are a darker colour, including the space between the two lines.

Is there any way in which this can be resolved?

Thanks.

```css
h2 span.spacer {
   padding:0 5px;
}
h2 span { 
   color: white; 
   font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   padding: 10px; 
}
h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 50px; 
   left: 0; 
}
```

```html
<h2><span>This is the first line.<span class="spacer"></span><br/><span class="spacer"></span>This is the second line.</span></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```css
h2 span.spacer {
   padding:0 5px;
}
h2 span { 
   color: white; 
   font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   padding: 10px; 
   display: inline-block;
}
h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 50px; 
   left: 0; 
}
```

```html
<h2><span>This is the first line.<span class="spacer"></span><br/><span class="spacer"></span>This is the second line.</span></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: Removed line between two spans**

This, right? Not sure what's happening, when I post this, it shows only plain HTML :/ Hope you're seeing it properly though.

```css
h2 span { 
   color: white; 
   font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   padding: 9px 10px;
}
h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 50px; 
   left: 0; 
}
```

```html
<h2><span>This is the first line.</span><br/><span>This is the second line.</span></h2>
```

Result: 
[image]
Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes I'm seeing it fine here - thanks. Its better but just wanting to the text to be aligned with one another. However, it has got rid of the blocks I was experiencing.

Comment: Looks brilliant, just wondered how I get rid of that line. Its an overlap between the two elements. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I just adjusted the top and bottom padding. See new update.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
h2 span.spacer {
   
}
h2 span { 
   color: white; 
   font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   padding: 10px; 
}
h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 80px; 
   left: 0; 
}
```

```html
<h2><span>This is the first line.</span><br/><span>This is the second line.</span></h2>
```